# How to solve InvalidDeploymentException: Application identity is not set?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 at the top where i declare the variables i have this line:

```
private string ArchiveLogFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\Archive log file";
```

In LocalUserAppDataPath i see:

```
C:\Users\000\AppData\Local\mws\mws\1.0.0.5
```

I have the directory 1.0.0.5 but it's empty and why is it going to this directory at all ?

This is the exception message:

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message=Application identity is not set.
  HResult=-2146233087
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Application identity is not set.
  Source=System.Deployment
  StackTrace:
       at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled the exception:

Open the Exceptions window from the Debug menu.
Expand "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" -> "System.Deployment.Application".
Uncheck the box next to "System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException".

Comment: but why? Sounds like you are hiding a problem.